mod_rewrite to hide sub-folders but not the file being accessed
I am trying to apply a rewrite rule that will hide all sub-folders leaving the file being accessed
here is  what i have done it does not work.
for example if i have a url like this:
www.mysite.com/product/admin/docs/info.php
the rewrite rule should change it to this:
www.mysite.com/product/info.php
in other words, anything after product must be hidden except info.php
#Redirection code starts

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /product/  

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)$ /$1 [L]


If that last RewriteRule in your posted implementation is meant to rewrite incoming requests from /product/info.php to /product/admin/docs/info.php, then where should the /admin/docs/ in that come from?
I would suggest something like that:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]+)$ /product/admin/docs/$1 [L]

That rule can be implemented in the central http server's host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that, in a distributed condiguration file (typically called .htaccess) which would have to be placed inside the http host's DocumentRoot folder.
That would be a variant for a distributed configuration file stored inside the /product folder, if such folder exists in the file system:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ admin/docs/$1 [L]

